# test concurrent map read and map write

Tags: go

I am a newcomer to the go language. When I execute the code, I get the following error：
fatal error: concurrent map read and map write

```golang
func foo() {
    var m = map[string]int{"a": 1}
    var lock = sync.RWMutex{}

    go Read(m, lock)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    go Write(m, lock)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
}

func main() {
    foo()
}

func Read(m map[string]int, lock sync.RWMutex) {
    for {
        read(m, lock)
    }
}

func Write(m map[string]int, lock sync.RWMutex) {
    for {
        write(m, lock)
    }
}

func read(m map[string]int, lock sync.RWMutex) {
    lock.RLock()
    defer lock.RUnlock()
    _ = m["a"]
}

func write(m map[string]int, lock sync.RWMutex) {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    m["b"] = 2
}
```

anyone can tell me why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must pass a pointer to your `sync.RWMutex` value. Otherwise, you're making copies of the mutex every time you pass it to a new function, so no actual locking happens.

The `go vet` tool will detect this error for you. You should run `go vet` (and likely [other linters](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint)) on all your code, to help catch such common errors. [Related reading](https://medium.com/golangspec/detect-locks-passed-by-value-in-go-efb4ac9a3f2b).